# Setting up virtual machine to recover from malware

Tags: debugging, virtual-machines

I'm running two virtual machines with Windows 7 (host OS Mac) using Virtualbox which I'd like to use to analyze malware. I have configured Visual Studio debugging and WinDBG, as well as other tools.

What's the best way to save a backup of the victim machine to quickly recover from damage caused by malware? Should I make a .zip of the entire Virtualbox folder and store it elsewhere?

---

Additional question: is it safe to run malware on a virtual machine with bridged adapter network settings for VS remote debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save and restore your VM's state, use snapshots: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots

> With snapshots, you can save a particular state of a virtual machine
>   for later use. At any later time, you can revert to that state, even
>   though you may have changed the VM considerably since then. A snapshot
>   of a virtual machine is thus similar to a machine in "saved" state, as
>   described above, but there can be many of them, and these saved states
>   are preserved.

[image: VirtualBox Snapshots]

Please create a separate Stack Exchange question for your second question.